# Jacobian factor for orthogonal decomposition with respect to vector

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Let $z\in S^2$. Fix vector $v\in S^2$. Then we can write $z=\langle z,v\rangle v+ \sqrt{\left(1- \langle z,v\rangle^2\right ) } v^{ \perp} $ where $v^{\perp}\in S^2$ such that $v$ and $v^{\perp}$ are orthogonal. Let $a= \langle z,v\rangle  $

We need to change variable from $z\to (a,v^{ \perp})$, then $dz= J(a,v^{\perp})dadv^{\perp}$. I am interested in finding the jacobian factor $J$. Is there any way to find that? I tried hard. But I could not get it.

Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is $dz$? area form on the sphere? Also, how can $z\mapsto (a,v^\top)$ be a change of variables if $z\in S^2$, $v^\top$ is fixed (as $v$ is fixed) and $a$ is a scalar?

Comment: v^T can be any vector which is perpendicular to $v$. It can vary over circle

Comment: We need to integrate over sphere that measure is $dz$

Comment: You said $v$ is fixed, so how does $v^\perp$ vary with $z$?

Comment: V perp is notation . There is can vary over circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me work with Euclidean coordinates,
$$
z=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in S^2.
$$

There certainly exists an orthogonal transformation $L:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ such that $Lv=(1,0,0)$. Fix such an $L$ and denote $Lz=(x_1',x_2',x_3')$.

The coordinate transformation is $z\mapsto (a,t)$ where
$$
a=\langle z,v\rangle=\langle Lz,Lv\rangle = x'_1
$$
and
$$
(\cos t,\sin t)=\frac 1{\sqrt{1-a^2}}(x_2',x_3')=v^\perp.
$$
(Whenever $a\not=1$, i.e. for all $z\not=v$.)

Let us use also the spherical coordinates
$$
x_1'=\cos\theta,\ \
x_2'=\sin\theta\cos\phi,\ \
x_3'=\sin\theta\sin\phi.
$$
Hence, $a=\cos\theta$, $\sin\theta\mathrm d\theta=\mathrm da$, $t=\phi$. The area form $\mathrm dz$ is
$$
\mathrm dz = \sin\theta \mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta = \mathrm da\, \mathrm dt.
$$
(Here we use that $L$ is an isometry of $\mathbb R^3$ hence it preserves the area form on the sphere $S^2$.)

The coordinates you are describing are just rotated spherical coordinates. I am using the coordinate $t$ to describe the vector $v^\perp$.